# Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists (in my localmachine)

Tags: 8, emails

I am using drupal on local machine .I am getting this error as Error : Unable to send email

The below is the report.
 [image]

Comment: why negative. Is this such a bad question

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) Please edit your question and include the steps we need to do to reproduce this error. We don't know your setup, your Drupal and what mails you are talking about. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess negative because the post lack of details. Including Drupal Core version (6, 7, 8, 9 ?), name of the modules used to send mails (and it's version), which are required to provide some help/assistance, excpectally if you're not very familliar with Drupal :)

You're saying running the site under local environment, does it provide a mail-sender ? If not, mails can't be sent, then Drupal tell you "Mails can't be send". Nothing more.

If your env is providing a sender, please check if that one is properly configured to send mails (you can found various one-line-commands to check that point)

And then, if both of previous tests were successful, check under Drupal settings if you haven't misspelled a port or a service name (postfix, sendmail ...)

Comment: thanks Ben for your answer. I havent done anything to set up to provide mail-sender